# Delphi Datasnap server with out/var type parameters

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have my application running in Delphi 10.1 with Datasnap server and client application.

There are few methods declared in the server with parameters "out/var"

```
Eg: sum (out a: widestring) or sum (var a: widestring)
```

When I try to generate classes from client application connecting to the server, it does not generate classes pas file when functions or procedures with out/var are available.

Please suggest.

Comment: It does for me (Delphi 10.1 Datasnap REST server and Delphi client). What proxy do you use ?, your client is also a Delphi app, Javascript, ... ... ?.

Comment: actually the parameters are of type widestring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WideString is not a supported type in DataSnap server methods. You can see a list of supported parameter types here: [Exposing DataSnap Server Methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Exposing_DataSnap_Server_Methods)

Comment: Thanks..!! I resolved it using OleVariant as the parameter datatype